# Help with MySQL gem on OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, configuration, rubygems

I'm trying to get the mysql gem working on OSX 10.5.6, and feeling stymied.

```
% gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql-2.7
1 gem installed
% irb -rubygems -rmysql
irb> Mysql.init
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Users/rampion/.gem/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /Users/rampion/.gem/gems/mysql-2.7/lib/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

zsh: trace trap  irb -rubygems -rmysql
%
```

I'm using the default install of ruby 1.8.6.

I'm using a 64-bit version of MySQL 5.0.77.  `mysqld` is running and I can use the mysql shell, so I suspect my issue is with `mysql.gem`, though I'm by no means certain.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  So the solution turned out to be I needed to be runing the 32-bit version of MySQL 5.0.77 in order for `mysql.gem` to work.